# How can I use roses in cooking?

Tags: culinary-uses, flowers

I have some very pungent roses in bloom at the moment, on smelling them my first thought was that they smelled like Turkish Delight. My Second thought that was it should be possible to use them in a pudding of some sort myself.

I have seen rose water in some recipes, is this the only way to use roses in cooking? What is a good way to get the flavor into food?

Comment: as this asks for a type of list of uses, you may want to alter this to a community wiki that involves uses of roses in cooking.

Comment: The reason they smell like Turkish Delight (loukoum) is that rosewater is a main ingredient. Also in baklawa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rose petals are edible.  If you look for rose petal recipes, you will find many creative uses of them, including rice pudding with roses - so your pudding intuition was correct.  During colonial American times they were considered a treat.  You can candy rose petals with egg whites and sugar - typical cautions about appropriate raw egg white useage applies.

Before using your rose petals in culinary applications, make sure to remember what chemicals you used on them.  If they've been sprayed with pesticides, you don't want to be eating them.

Comment: This helped me to understand many uses for one specific flower.THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're making a Persian dish with rice, then add some [rose water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_water) to the cooking water. The rice then becomes very fragrant. I like it with slightly sweet pork dishes.

This raises the question of how to make rose water from rose petals. I'm not sure, but I'm guessing you could just put them in a (clean!) cloth bag and add that to the water instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use them to make marmalade, or (with a slightly more complex process), you can perform steam distillation of the petals and extract the essential oils, which you can use as a very pleasant aroma (after dilution) in ice creams and popsicles.

Remember that it's very important to have pesticides-free petals.

Answer (score 0):

as one of the other visitors mentioned, be careful not to use rose petals that have been sprayed with who knows what.

An alternative is to use rose petals (or the green leaves of the rose,for that matter) of organic certified roses from ecuador, check www.nevadoroses.com, or the latest news about edible certified organic roses in [this Reuters article](http://in.mobile.reuters.com/mobile/m/AnyArticle/p.rdt?URL=http://in.reuters.com/article/idINTRE68C57A20100913)

Disclaimer: The website is for my company, and the article is about me and my company

Comment: Hi roberto nevado, welcome to the site.  Whilst we do allow some self promotion here it must be disclosed.  I have added a disclaimer to your answer, and reformatted a little.  Hope this is ok. Please see the [faq](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq) and also [this discussion](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/328/is-it-appropriate-allowed-to-link-your-own-websites-in-your-answers-to-question) about it.  Please continue to use the site, just stay within rules.  Thanks :)